# Ace Editor escaping $ inside snippet definitions

Tags: ace-editor

I'm trying to create the following snippet:

```
200:
  description: ${1: description}
  schema:
    $ref: ${2: schema definition reference}
```

This is a JSON schema fragment. I'm trying to escape the `$` in `$ref:`. However, `\$ref` only removes the entire word. How can I make Ace to use `$ref` literally in the snippet?

Answer (score 3):

The correct way seems to be `\\$ref: ${2: schema definition reference}`.

Comment: note that \\ is needed only in js string, in snippets file on backslash works, but in js string \ itself needs to be escaped.